# Camel 3.20.5 - MongDbConstants.FIELDS_PROJECTION doesn't work when set from a processor

Tags: java, apache-camel

Both codes are equivalent, but the first one works and returns the field specified in the projection (and _id), while the second one fails and returns all fields of the documents

```java
from("direct:resources")
    .setHeader(MongoDbConstants.FIELDS_PROJECTION, constant("{identity:1}"))
    .setHeader(MongoDbConstants.CRITERIA, constant("{_id:{$in:['542e696a-30b4-4074-a6a1-69c1c000f711','5714a9ec-3349-41d1-819e-937068e1ef41']}}"))
    .to("mongodb:mongo?database={{resources.db}}&collection={{resources.collection}}&operation=findAll")
    .process(exchange -> {
        var body = (List<Document>)exchange.getIn().getBody();
        exchange.getMessage().setBody(body);
    });
```

```java
from("direct:resources")
    .process(exchange -> {
        //exchange.getIn().setHeader(MongoDbConstants.FIELDS_PROJECTION, constant(Projections.include("identity")));
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(MongoDbConstants.FIELDS_PROJECTION, constant("{identity:1}"));
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(MongoDbConstants.CRITERIA, Filters.in("_id", List.of("542e696a-30b4-4074-a6a1-69c1c000f711","5714a9ec-3349-41d1-819e-937068e1ef41")));
    })
    .to("mongodb:mongo?database={{resources.db}}&collection={{resources.collection}}&operation=findAll")
    .process(exchange -> {
        var body = (List<Document>)exchange.getIn().getBody();
        exchange.getMessage().setBody(body);
    });
```

```xml
<camel.version>3.20.5</camel.version>

...
            
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>

...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-mongodb-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```